# Remove Trailing Zeros when Casting to Money

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

How to remove the zeros

```
  select CONVERT(varchar, CAST( -3563338 AS money), 1)
```

Output

```
-3,563,338.00
```

Expected Output

```
-3,563,338
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `FORMAT`:

```
SELECT FORMAT(-3563338,'#,###,##0')

-3,563,338
```

The money type output includes a decimal component for change.  But, since you don't want to see that it might be easier to just use `FORMAT` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try below - using `replace()` function

```
select replace(CONVERT(varchar, CAST( -3563338 AS money), 1),'.00','')
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select TO_CHAR(-3563338.00,'99999999') from dual;
```

Comment: Can you explain how `TO_CHAR` formats a number and why not to use the more appropriate `FORMAT`?

Comment: This is Oracle syntax, not applicable to SQL Server